# Previsão de demanda Método Monte Carlo

Tags: sql, oracle

Boa noite pessoal, estou desenvolvendo um select com o objetivo de simular uma previsão de demanda na minha empresa, estou utilizando o método de Monte Carlo, que usa uma função para gerar valores aleatórios dentro da função distributiva. Alguém tem conhecimento de qual a função ou como aplicar a inversa da distribuição num select no banco Oracle? Uso a ferramenta SQLTools.
Segue um artigo que estou usando como apoio, pagina 11 esta a formula quando aplicado no Excel. Obrigado a atenção

http://pos.federalnoar.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/PREVIS%C3%83O-DE-DEMANDA-POR-MEIO-DO-M%C3%89TODO-DE-SIMULA%C3%87%C3%83O-DE-MONTE-CARLOS-EM-UMA-LOJA-DE-CONVENI%C3%8ANCIA.pdf

Comment: O pdf não baixou no meu tablet mas Oracle tem ampla gama de funções estatísticas , https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/bi-datawarehousing.html   ... https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/analysis.htm#i1007362

Comment: Melhora a pergunta , modelo dos dados , definição do problema e a "página 11". Um modelo mais simples como regressão linear ou médias môveis não resolve ?

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invers%C3%A3o_de_Moro

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20070505093933/http://home.online.no/~pjacklam/notes/invnorm/#Oracle_PLSQL